# Video Autoplays after the Display CSS attribute is set to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe with the src being a website that has a video on autoplay. The iframe has `display:none;` css attribute. I have tried setting `autoplay="false"` on my iframe but the video still autoplay. here is my code

```
<iframe id="content_cb2" autoplay="false" src="http://www.tablettraining.net/"></iframe></a>
```

css

```
#content_cb2{

   width: 100%; 
    height: 500px;
display: none;

}
```

And here is the fiddle. You'll notice the video will autoplay
http://jsfiddle.net/uprosoft/csRWe/

Any help to stop the video from auto-playing is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually the video in that page is loaded from Vimeo..**

You can embed directly in your page without the need of tablettraining.net

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/59917891?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

You see that url parameter "autoplay=1", this how you set it to autoplay!

Comment: I need the whole website in an iframe but the video not to autoplay. Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that, because you can't control what the page in iframe is doing unless it is yours..